# Spyder-IDE - *.py script don't add variables to variable explorer

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, geopandas

I am trying to read a `geojson` file via `SHP = geopandas.read_file('filename.geojson')` in Spyder-IDE under use of Anaconda and Spyder 3.3.6 + Python 3.7. It used to work just fine but then at some point it suddenly stopped working. Whenever I now run the file, I receive `NameError: name 'basinsSHP' is not defined`. The weird thing is, I can still copy and paste the command into the console and it works fine. `SHP` shows up in the variable explorer. I've looked into this and it seems that also other variables cannot be added to the Variable Explorer via that specific script. However, when I copy and paste the line above into another script it's working. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using multiple consoles? If so, it is possible that your script runs in another console with different namespace

Comment: I am not using multiple consoles :(